# What are the UILApplication and UILWidgetProvider class from Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

Referencing to the Universal Image Loader from nostra13:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

In his sample code, there are two files called UILApplication.java and UILWidgetProvider.java

I can't find where these two files are referenced, and why they are important. Without these codes, the application crashes. Can anyone explain the purpose of these files and where they are called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILWidgetProvider.java provides widgets 
 You are extending your application  to nostraimage loader.
so u need to write class like given below...and you need to change ur application name in manifest also

```
         android:name="MyApplication"
```

.Hope this helps...

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new         ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        ...
        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this! It really helped explained everything :)

Comment: So all these initialisations can be done in the First Activity also right ? May be in a splash screen ?